# Problem on finding the set of biases and weights in a specific neural network

Tags: proof-verification, machine-learning, neural-networks

I have a doubt regarding an exercise [here](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html). Suppose that we have a neural network that tries to map a $28\times 28$ image of a digit to what digit it actually represents. So we have a neural network like this:

[image]

The activation function is calculated for each output neuron and the neuron with the highest activation value ends up "firing" (i.e. if output neuron 1 has the highest activation function value, then the model thinks the digit is 1).

With that background, here's the actual problem:

> There is a way of determining the bitwise representation of a digit by adding an extra layer to the three-layer network above. The extra layer converts the output from the previous layer into a binary representation, as illustrated in the figure below. Find a set of weights and biases for the new output layer. Assume that the first $3$ layers of neurons are such that the correct output in the third layer (i.e., the old output layer) has activation at least $0.99$, and incorrect outputs have activation less than $0.01$.
>
> [image]

So here I'm assuming the "perceptron rule", i.e. the following activation function for the final layer:

$y^{(i)} = 0$ if $(b + \sum_jw^{(i)}_jx_j) \leq 0$

$y^{(i)} = 1$ if $(b + \sum_jw^{(i)}_jx_j) > 0$

where $j \in \{0,1,2,\ldots,9\}$ and $i \in \{1,2,3,4\}$. Since $x_i < 0.01$ for any incorrect output, I guess the weight $w^{(i)}_j=1$ if the $i$-th bit in the binary representation of digit $j$ is $1$. As an example, since $9$ is $1001$ in binary, $w^{(1)}_9=w^{(4)}_9=1$ and $w^{(2)}_9=w^{(3)}_9=0$.

In that scenario, the maximum number of digits that have $1$ in any of the $4$ bits is $5$ - that's because the $4$-th bit of $1,3,5,7,9$ is $1$. A worst case scenario is if the actual digit is $6$, so $x_6 \geq 0.99$ and all other $x_i$'s $<0.01$. Also, $w^{(1)}_6 =w^{(3)}_6= w^{(5)}_6=w^{(7)}_6=w^{(9)}_6=1$, which means $\sum_jw^{(i)}_jx_j$ is only slightly less than $0.05$, meaning that the bias term $b=-0.05$.

Is this approach/answer correct? I'm not sure if I'm missing something here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning, for the most part, is correct. However, as the sigmoid function deals with real numbers in the interval $[0, 1]$, the weights and biases you've chosen are not ideal. Suppose the input was an image of the number $3$, in this case, the $3$rd ($4$th if you're counting from 1) neuron in the third layer is $> 0.99$ while all the other neurons in that layer are $< 0.01$.

Here, $w.x+b$ according to your set of weights and biases give a result of some number $ > 0.94$ for the $0$th output neuron. Taking $z = 0.94$ as input to the sigmoid function, we'd get an output of around $0.28$ for the $0$th neuron. This would logically be a 0. But, for a 3, this neuron must output a 1.

This is happening as the inputs are bounded in the interval $[0, 1]$. If the weights are only $0$ or $1$, the effective value of $z=w.x+b$ can atmost be a one and in the worst case, b. As the term $e^{-z}$ requires a bigger value for $z$ to make it zero, consider increasing the weights to be $10$ and $-10$ instead of $1$ and $0$. The bias can be any value as it doesn't play a major role in deciding the output of a sigmoid neuron, atleast in this particular case.